# Python上の小数を含む数を，Arduinoが扱える形に成形したいです．

Tags: python, c++, c, raspberry-pi, arduino

現在，pythonで計算した値，例えば，pi=3.141592 をArduinoに渡そうと考えています．(とりあえずはI2Cで）
今回は「piを4bytesに分ける」「分けて送信して後でArduinoが4byte繋げる」ということを目標にしています．strに直す方法などもありますが，自分の勉強のためにこの方法で進めようと思っています．

そこで，わからない点が，「Python上でpiをどうすれば，Arduinoが後から読める形にできるのか」ということです．例えば，piを structのpackメソッドを使って，f(32bit float)の4バイトの配列を作りました

```
from struct import pack
pi=3.141592
b=pack("f",　pi)
```

これで，Arduinoが後から読める形になったと思います．なので後はこの配列を順番にわたします．

```
bus.write(adress, b[0])
bus.write(adress, b[1])
bus.write(adress, b[2])
bus.write(adress, b[3])
```

後は，Arduio側ではbitシフトをしながら繋げていくだけで, floatとしてpiが受け取れるはずです．しかし，うまくいきません．原因は受け取る側（arduino)にも考えられるかもしれませんが，別の実験でうまく動いたプログラムなので，Arduinoには問題がないと仮定してそのプログラムは割愛します．
とにかく，現在私の中で問題があるのではないかと思うのが，繰り返しになりますが，

「 Python上でpiを，Arduinoが後から読める形に変換できていない」「あるいは変換できているけれど，分割して送れていない」

ということです．必ずしもこのコードを訂正していただく必要はなく，皆様の知っている変換方法，分割方法も教えて下さいませ

よろしくお願いします

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pythonで作成したバイト列の内容を表示すると、Windowsでは以下のようになりますが、Raspberry Piではどうなっていますか？

```
b'\xd8\x0fI@'
```

上記の順番が以下のように逆に表示されるなら：

```
b'@I\x0f\xd8'
```

変換の際にエンディアンを明示的に指定してみれば良いと思われます。

```
b=pack("<f", pi)
```

---

Arduinoのボードや環境は持っていないのでソースコード上の扱いになりますが、前回の回答で紹介した以下の記事を参考に、通信はしないで上記のバイト配列を即値で設定した場合にどのような値が表示されるでしょう？
[Convert IEEE 754 32 to float](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/convert-ieee-754-32-to-float/323109)

```
union 
{      byte b[4] ;
        float f ;
} u ;

u.b[0] = '\xd8' ;
u.b[1] = '\x0f' ;
u.b[2] = 'I' ;
u.b[3] = '@' ;

Serial.println( u.f ) ;
```

上記で表示が`3.141592`といったπの数値ではなく、別の値だったら、どこかで変換する処理が必要になるでしょう。
上記でπの数値が正しく表示されるなら、Raspberry PiとArduinoの間の通信が何か上手くいっていない可能性があります。

ちなみにVC++で同様に以下のように作成・実行した場合は`3.141592`が表示されました。

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    union {
        unsigned char b[4];
        float         f;
    } u;

    u.b[0] = '\xd8';
    u.b[1] = '\x0f';
    u.b[2] = 'I';
    u.b[3] = '@';

    printf("%f\n", u.f);
}
```

---

そして質問ではRaspberry Pi, Pythonから`bus.write(adress, b[0])`と言う風に送信していて、おそらく[smbus2](https://pypi.org/project/smbus2/)の`Example 5: Single i2c_rdwr`あたりの書き方を参考にしているのでしょうが、微妙に合っていない(かつ記述が不足している)ようです。

上記PyPIページの記述に合わせるか、前回の回答で紹介した以下の記事のように、smbus2の(基となった？)少し前の[smbus](https://pypi.org/project/smbus/)のライブラリを使ってみてはどうでしょう？
[Raspberry PiでI2C通信をする](https://www.raspberrypirulo.net/entry/raspberrypi-i2c)
[ラズパイ（Raspberry Pi）とArduinoをI2Cで接続【基本編】 ラズパイからPythonのSMBusモジュールを使ってArduinoにデータを送信しよう](https://deviceplus.jp/raspberrypi/raspberry-pi-and-arduino-connect-with-i2c-01/)

Comment: またもやありがとうございます．はい，私のパソコンでもkunifさん同様，即値の受け渡しをすればうまくいきました．ということは，Arduinoに渡す過程で何かがおかしくなっているのですかね．．．少し追加で質問させていただきたいです

Comment: I2C, SPI何の通信規格を使うにしろ，汎用な理解をつけたいと思っています．
まず，どのような送信方法であれ，バイトを一つずつ送信して，後で繋げるという基本発想は変わりません．
そして話をわかりやすくするために，packを使わずに考えてみます．

Raspiが pi=3.141592という数を作るとします．これを，「Arduinoが後から読める形に送ることができていて 」「Arduino内での受け取り後の処理が間違っていなければ」，目的は達成されるはずです．


kunifさんのおかげで，PC内やりとり（つまりPytho内やりとり）ではpackを使って正しい分割ができていることが確認できました．
今，問題なのでは，それが「Arduinoが後から読める形」なのかということです．

Comment: 例えば，
bus.write(adress,  '\xd8)
bus.write(adress, '\x0f’)
bus.write(adress, ‘I’)
bus.write(adress, ‘@‘)

とはできません．なぜなら少なくとも私の知る限りでは，Raspiが送るのはつまるところ0-255の数であるからです．
(もちろん，,  '\xd8 をstrで送ることもできますが， それにはまた送る前にstrをbyteに変換する必要があり，まるで ”数を送るための文字を数に変換する”みたいな二度手間，三度手間になっています）

Comment: そこで私は，じゃあ最初から，「Arduinoが普段floatを扱っている形式で送ってやろう」と発送しました．それがIEEE754です．https://tools.m-bsys.com/calculators/ieee754.php . Arduinoではpi=3.1518492を 40490fd8 として扱っているそうなので，

bus.write(adress,  0x40)
bus.write(adress, 0x49)
bus.write(adress, 0x0f)
bus.write(adress, 0xd8)

として送り，後はArduinoで，４回受け取った後にbitシフトを使って，


    float result = (uint32_t) (
          (((uint32_t)data[0] << 24) & 0xFF000000)
        | (((uint32_t)data[1] << 16) & 0x00FF0000)
        | (((uint32_t)data[2] <<  8) & 0x0000FF00)
        | (((uint32_t)data[3] <<  0) & 0x000000FF)
    );

のように再結合すれば良いと思っています

Comment: しかしこれがうまくいきません．．なぜでしょうか？（ちなみに16進数 0x12345678 を 0x12 0x34 0x45  0x78と分けて送るとうまくいきます．これは16進数だからですかね？　Rapiでそもそもpiを16進数にすればよいかもしれませんが方法がわかりません…)

コードが見にくくてすみません．コメントでコードブロックを作れないようです...

Comment: それはリトルエンディアン/ビッグエンディアンの扱いを間違えて処理しています。わざわざ値をシフトせずに、回答に紹介したArduinoのIEEE754記事のように受信した順番にbyte配列のバッファに詰めていって4バイト揃ったら浮動小点数として見做せば良いだけです。あるいはArduino側の処理を変えたくないのなら、Raspberry Pi側のデータ作成処理を変えてビッグエンディアン形式(`b=pack(">f", pi)`)を試してみてはどうでしょう？

Answer (score 0):

> ということです．必ずしもこのコードを訂正していただく必要はなく，皆様の知っている変換方法，分割方法も教えて下さいませ

文字列で渡してそこから変換すればよろしいかと。

Comment: ありがとうございます．しかし今はバイト別の送信方法を試したいのです

Comment: python上での小数点表現がどういう形式で行われてるのか、Arduinoでの浮動小数点表現がどういう形式なのか、を調べて、その上でどーこーしないといけません。
そのうえ、その双方とも、規格ではっきり決まっているわけではないので、実行環境や、言語のバージョンによっても変わる可能性もあります。
そこらへんを把握できていない、できないなら、あっさり文字列で、"3.141592"を通信させたほうがよろしいかと思います

Comment: なるほど，確かにそうかもしれません．．．しかし最終目標であるspiでの通信(Master: Rpi,  Slave: Arduino）についての，strを利用した通信方法という記事もなかなか見つかりませんでしたので，もう少し頑張ってみます